# window.location make chrome jump with jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

When clicking on a link, I am generating a link to a clickonce app via an ajax call. When ajax returns the generated link successfully I set `window.location = my_generated_link;`

This works well in IE9, i.e. the clickonce is downloaded and I stay at the current page,

however in Chrome the I am navigated back to a previous page

(the clickonce will still be downloaded however, but its annoying to be navigated away from my current page).

Anyone got ideas?

Answer (score 0):

make sure your window.location =newlocation is execute after completing your ajax request
may be your `window.location = my_generated_link;` execute before your ajax request

like this

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body
}).done(function() { 
  window.location = my_generated_link;
});
```

Comment: The link is generated correctly so I don't think that is the issue. Changing location on 'success'

Comment: 1. try `window.top.location` insted of `window.location` 2. put `alert(my_generated_link);` and check its not empty or begin with http://

Comment: why not begin with http:// ? (the link will sometimes start with http:// and sometimes https://)

Comment: if your link start with different domain its require witch protocol you use

Comment: can you paste here what `my_generated_link` what return ?

Comment: something like: "htt p://fus.ro.net/fus/dah.application?something=somedata"

Comment: can give me a link of your application ?

Comment: unfortunately not, however it seems I might be able to do without solving this issue. But thanks alot for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Take a hidden IFrame and give my_generated_link url to the source of that Iframe. Also add a parameter cofc_goback=false to the my_generated_link i.e.

```
my_generated_link = my_generated_link + "&cofc_goback=false";
$('iframe').prop("src",my_generated_link);
```

This worked perfectly for me in all the browsers.